# Concatenate multiple images vertically using convert produces many outputs

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to append multiple .jpg files into a single large image file containing the result of vertically stacking the single ones.
It seems to me that Imagemagick's `convert` has a somewhat erratic behavior when it comes to `-append`, i.e vertical wise, when I try to expand a list of files passed as wildcard argument like in the instruction `convert -append pg*.jpg out.jpg`.

This command creates one output file for every source image there is in the directory. Even then those files aren't concatenations. They are simply copies of the original ones. I would expect one single output with the stacking.

It works just fine using `+append`, for horizontal stacking.
Also works when I type in the name of each individual file, `convert -append pg-01.jpg pg-02.jpg pg-03.jpg pg-04.jpg ... output.jpg`.
The expansion (*) works for a small subset of files, like 7 or 8.

I tried this
`` convert -append `for x in img/pg-*; do echo $x; done;` img/out.jpg ``
in the terminal but I don't know why it doesn't work!

Since I'm working with a bunch of images, I looking to know if there is any alternative for GNU/Linux or why it is behaving like this.

I'll appreciate any info.

Edit:
I forgot to mention that I  get this error: `` convert-im6.q16: width or height exceeds limit `pg-01.jpg' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3911. `` when the unexpected output occurs. All images have the same width/height.

Comment: Put the "-append" after the list of images. Normal behavior for IM is to read in the files before doing something with them.

Comment: Okay. I just tried `convert pg-*.jpg -append out.jpp`. Still same problem. Also I forgot to mention that I  get this error: ```convert-im6.q16: width or height exceeds limit `pg-01.jpg' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3911.``` when the unexpected output occurs... I'll add it to the question. All imgs have the same width/height (1241x1755)

Answer (score 0):

Commenting these lines:

```
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="16KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="16KP"/>
```

In `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` appears to have solved the issue.